# 'perlbrew list-modules' does return 'Perl' and nothing else

Tags: multithreading, perlbrew

I've ubuntu 16.04 and i've installed perl 5.8.7,5.18.2 both with threads activated, and 5.18.1 without threads.
The purpose was to use a version of Perl with threads instead of forks as i've mutiple scripts already done with threds and forks is not a proper multi-threading models (it just forks processes).
The first problem i get is when installing modules via cpanm -fi [name_of_module] command. As a matter of fact the command doesnt' return anything at all! just 'Perl'. The same fact happens when i'm traying to instal wathever modules i desire using in my scrips.
I think this problem is linked with the fact i'm able to use ''treads'' just when i run the scripts without sudo (e.g.perl [name_of_the_script]), while when i run it with 'sudo perl [name_of_the_script]' says 'the current version of Perl doesn't support threads'!
That's quite strange.
The perlbrew enviroment veriables are set up correctly and when i type ''which perl'', the system poits to the new-version directory as expected.

Dont' know how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

I see that you posted several question in one paragraph. I'll try to answer the onse that I could.

## `cpanm -fi XXX` does not "return anything at all"

I'm not sure I get this part. If `XXX` failed to be installed, there should probably be some error messages on the screen. The fact that `perlbrew list-modules` prints nothing but `Perl` implies that probably nothing is installed.

It could be that your `cpanm` execuateble is implicityl installing stuff for system perl instead. You could verify this by checking the first line of `head =cpanm`. If it is not `#!/usr/bin/env perl`, it is probably wrong. You want the one installed by: `perlbrew install-cpanm`

## sudo perl

I wonder if you PATH is actually correctly set -- Running `perl -V` after `perlbrew use 5.8.7` can show you enough version information and therefore tell you whether perlbrew itself is working properly.

You probably also need `sudo -E perl` instead. `sudo` reset env vars unless you ask it not to (the `-E` option), and PERL5LIB is probably needed.